# Connect Kivy application to Django database

Tags: python, django, sqlite, kivy

I 'd like to connect my Kivy application to my Django database (sqlite) with permissions **CRUD**.

I am not able to find a tutorial which describes how to make this connection

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show some attempt at what you've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too broad of a question.

Open your website through a restful API. Use requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to make restful requests to your website and get data.